# Validation Rule not firing after new records is created, only existing

Tags: formula-field, validation

Validation Rule is only working for existing records. When new records are created and edited the VR is not firing.

Multi-Selection picklist, there are 2 choices: Project manager (default) Accountable Executive.
2 Look up fields: Accountable Executive, Project Manager
Checkbox

If checkbox is true, picklist and/or Project Manager/Accountable Executive then Look up field must not be blank. (I have separated Project manager and Accountable Executive into 2 Validation Rules)

```
AND( Nominate_PaaG_Delivery__c = TRUE,
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Project_Manager__c ))),
OR(
INCLUDES(PaaG_Recipients__c, "Project Manager")
)
)
```

Comment: `NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Project_Manager__c )))` will never be true on insert.

Answer (score 0):

You would need two validation rules if you want to show different error messages. Otherwise, you can combine them into one. Try this..

```
AND(
 Nominate_PaaG_Delivery__c = TRUE,
 OR(
    AND(
      INCLUDES( PaaG_Recipients__c,'Project Manager' ),
      ISBLANK( Project_Manager__c )  
    ),
    AND(
      INCLUDES( PaaG_Recipients__c,'Accountable Executive' ),
      ISBLANK( Accountable_Executive__c )  
    )  
 )
)
```

If you want to write individual validation rules, then it is

```
AND(
 Nominate_PaaG_Delivery__c = TRUE,
 INCLUDES( PaaG_Recipients__c,'Project Manager' ),
 ISBLANK( Project_Manager__c )  
)
```

Let me know if they work and for any other questions.